# Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter how remove item

Tags: android, listview

with few examples i have build this application, I would like to remove the item when I click on the imagebutton( declared on the row item xml)
I have tried to implement the callback invoked when the imagebuttom are pressed, but after how can delete/remove the item?
How can do that?
thx for all!

This is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Ordine ordine_data[] = new Ordine[]
                {
                    new Ordine("Cloudy1"),
                    new Ordine("Cloudy2"),
                    new Ordine("Cloudy3"),
                    new Ordine("Cloudy4"),
                    new Ordine("Cloudy5")
                };

        final ArrayList<Ordine> list = new ArrayList<Ordine>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ordine_data.length; ++i) {
          list.add(ordine_data[i]);
        }
        final OrdineAdapter adapter = new OrdineAdapter(this,R.layout.order_list_row, ordine_data);
         ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header, null);
        listview.addHeaderView(header);        
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        //final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        //listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

            final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            view.animate().setDuration(1000).alpha(0)
                .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    list.remove(item);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                  }
                });
          }

        });
    }




    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
          for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          String item = getItem(position);
          return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
          return true;
        }

      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is my adapter:

```
public class OrdineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ordine>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Ordine data[] = null;

    public OrdineAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Ordine[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        OrdineHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new OrdineHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);        
            row.setTag(holder);

            ImageButton btnRemove = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.remove_product);
            btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int i;
                    i=0; //this is for testing only!!!

                }

            });
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (OrdineHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Ordine ordine = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(ordine.title);


        return row;
    }

    static class OrdineHolder
    {

        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `ordine_data` to your `OridneAdapter`; there is no connection between your `list` variable and `ordine_data`. You are adding your `Ordines` to your `ArrayList`using `ordine_data`, but this doesn't mean that there is a link between the data you pass to the `OridneAdapter` and the `list` of `Ordines`. You need to use `remove()` in  `ViewAdapter`(the `parent` variable in your  case) to pass the `Ordine` to be removed , and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You can try this inside `run()`:

```
ArrayAdapter<Ordines> adapter = parent.getAdapter();
 adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, I think you need to call `start()` for your `Animation` to run.